# Why the CodeIgniter 2 does not support the Modular Extensions?

Tags: codeigniter, routes, module

After I was upggrading the CI 1.7 with Codeigniter 2 returns an Error and it shows as a routing error, its because of CodeIgniter 2 Routing library has little optimized. how to resolve this problem?

[alt text http://codeigniter.com/?ACT=51&fid=71&aid=11318_MsqswOnwiV00NskrfWQQ&board_id=2](http://codeigniter.com/?ACT=51&fid=71&aid=11318_MsqswOnwiV00NskrfWQQ&board_id=2)

Answer (score 2):

The scaffolding functionality of Codigniter has been depreciated since 1.6.

You need to go into **application/config/routes.php** and comment out:

```
//$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
```

Also it looks as though you need to also set your default controller:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "yourcontroller";
```

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "yourcontroller"; in this line 'yourcontroller' needs to be a controller class that you have made, otherwise put it back to the welcome controller

Answer (score 0):

ultimately I figureout the way of making work for modules, an online jurnal was posted by [phil sturgeon](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/03/modular-separation-codeigniter-2).  and to enable it, he has written a class whitch is hosted at [GitHub](http://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-modular-separation/)

Comment: And not to mention, this is for the DEV build - NOT the LIVE codebase... so of COURSE its not going to work 100% perfectly, its still in bug squashing phase!

Comment: hEY EYOOSUF,

I have installed a mushmellow module and routing is working pretty fine of my localhost.. but on when uploaded on server any route (wrt module) takes me to home page. Any idea.
above mentioned links of phil dont work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HMVC works fine with CodeIgniter 2.0, but you have to upgrade to a newer version.

A 1.7.2 version of code cannot be expected to work magically with 2.0 if it was made before 2.0 was developed. :)